# MVVM - How to handle anonymous types composed of models inside ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, mvvm, architecture

Currently my view has the need to receive a List containing information from two different models.

Something like this

```
public class ViewModel
{
    [JsonProperty("")]
    public List<Unknown> viewModelList;
}
```

This `Unknown` type would have information from two different models, like so.

```
public class FirstModel
{
    int w;
    int x;
}

public class SecondModel
{
    int y;
    int z;
}

public class Unknown //Model or ViewModel?
{
    [JsonProperty("")]
    int w; //From FirstModel

    [JsonProperty("")]
    int x; //From SecondModel
}
```

My question is, this `Unknown` type would have to be a Model? My idea of a Model is that they represent Business entities or Database entities, and ViewModel are abstractions of those models. In this case, `Unknown` is nothing, but an abstraction of both `FirstModel` and `SecondModel`, so I think it characterizes more as a ViewModel, than a Model, but then if I treat it as a ViewModel, I'm unable to make a List out of it, because otherwise my code would be as follows

```
public class ViewModel
{
    [JsonProperty("")]
    public List<UnknownViewModel> viewModelList;
}
```

It would be a ViewModel inside a ViewModel, and I don't know if this is common or good practice.

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely no functional difference in what you call it. What matters is how you use the types.

A *model* is simply a type that contains data (or state). And a *view-model*, as its name suggests, is the model used as the backing for a view (or presentation). That's all.

Here, in your example, you're using `Unknown` as a model -- one that's being used as the element type of a collection property of a type that will presumably be used as a view-model.